# Easy way to rewrite in a loop

Tags: java

Is there an easier way to write this code to make my image views invisible? I was hoping I could use some type of for loop. I am also new to programming so in your answer, can you please explain how the loop is working so I can use it in future references? Also, how do I assign 15 image views to 1 array?

```
        iv_1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_17.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_18.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_19.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_20.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_21.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_22.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_23.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_24.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_25.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_26.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_27.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_28.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_29.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_30.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_31.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_32.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_33.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_34.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_35.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_36.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_37.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_38.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_39.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_40.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_41.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_42.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_43.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_44.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_45.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_46.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_47.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_48.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_49.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_50.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_51.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_52.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_53.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_54.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_55.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_56.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_57.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_58.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_59.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_60.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your `iv_xx` objects in a list or array, then use a loop to iterate through the array:

```
ArrayList<IVType> ivList = new ArrayList<>();
// use ivList.add() to add each object to the list.
for (IVType iv: ivList)
{
  iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a array of size N of type img(Your object).
N—> will be the number of images.
img[] a=new img[N];
 Here, we are creating a array of type img with size N.

Now you need to add all your 50 image object to this array using for loop
 Then loop through the array and set the property like below.

```
for(int i =0; i<N;i++){
   a[i].setVisibilty(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume this is your POJO

```
public class ImageView {
    private View visibility;

    public ImageView(View view) {
        visibility = view;
    }

    public View getVisibility() {
        return visibility;
    }

    public void setVisibility(View visibility) {
        this.visibility = visibility;
    }

    enum View {
        VISIBLE, INVISIBLE
    }
}
```

Also, consider the scenario that you have already `ImageView` list that contains 60 image instances.

```
        List<ImageView> imageViews = new ArrayList<>();

        //instead of creating 60 beans separately and adding it to list you can just follow the below code

        IntStream.range(0, 60).forEach(e -> {
            imageViews.add(new ImageView(ImageView.View.INVISIBLE));
        });

        //you can manipulate the ImageView instances as below
        //imageViews.forEach(e -> e.setVisibility(ImageView.View.INVISIBLE));

        //As per the requirement you can convert the list into array as below. There is no need to mention the pre-sized array (new ImageView[imageViews.size()]) here
          ImageView[] imageViewsArr = imageViews.toArray(new ImageView[0]);

         //If you want to make a arrays of first 15 instances then you can limit the size to 15 (your question mentioned just 15 imageViews to 1 array) 
    //ImageView[] imageViewsArr = imageViews.stream().limit(15).toArray(new ImageView[0]);
```